# Регулярные выражения в php. Поиск подстроки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно вывести содержимое строки, которая находится между тегами .
Например, есть строки:

```
//какой-то код
<version>1</version>
//какой-то код
<version>1.1</version>
//какой-то код
<version>1.1.1</version>
//какой-то код
```

Необходимо запросом с регулярным выражением получить все эти строчки.
Пробовал так `"<version>(.*)</version>"`, но `preg_match` ничего не возвращает.

Comment: А заключить регурляку в косые `/регулярка/` и экранировать `/` в самой регулярке ...

Comment: Отлично, спасибо за ответ, всё заработало!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg_match` не возвращает саму найденную подстроку, но может записать результаты поиска в третий параметр. Для поиска всех вхождений у вас сработает такой код:

```
$str = '//какой-то код
<version>1</version>
//какой-то код
<version>1.1</version>
//какой-то код
<version>1.1.1</version>
//какой-то код';

preg_match_all("#<version>(.*)</version>#", $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Использовал решетки `#` в качестве ограничителя регулярки дабы не мучиться с экранированием `/`. Считаю что при работе с тегами так удобнее.

Если ищется только одно вхождение, то `preg_match_all` следует заменить на `preg_match`.

**UPD**
Как справедливо заметил пользователь **Naumov** в комментариях, не стоит использовать регулярные выражения для разбора XML или HTML. Лучше воспользоваться методами специальных расширений, например вариант со стандартным `SimpleXML`:

```
$str = <<<XML
<document>
    <!--какой-то код-->
    <version>1</version>
    <!--какой-то код-->
    <version>1.1</version>
    <!--какой-то код-->
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

var_dump($xml->version);
```

Comment: Т.е. если использовать символ `#` в начале и в конце регулярного выражения, то не нужно экранировать символы, которые находятся внутри? Или это работает только с символом `/`?

Comment: @Cuthbert_Allgood: Тут понимаете в чем дело, если ограничить косой чертой регулярку, то нужно экранировать все внутренние косые черты, чтоб компилятор не подумал что это конец регулярки. Если ограничить решеткой, то нужно экранировать все внутренние решетки. Сами понимаете, что решетка встречается намного, НАМНОГО реже, чем косая черта. Вообще символов, доступных для ограничения регулярок довольно много, я выбрал для себя решетку, а остальные забыл =)

Comment: @Cuthbert_Allgood: А все остальные символы, требующие экранирования, конечно же должны быть заэкранированы. Преимущества именно решеток в том, что вы сократите этот адский забор из заэкранированный символов. Сравните `"/http:\/\//"` и `"#http://#"`. Какая строка лучше читается?

Comment: Спасибо большое) Теперь понял, почему так)

Comment: @Cuthbert_Allgood: Незачто =)

Comment: У человека явный xml и все значения достаються простым `xpath` а вы ему регулярку впарили. Хороший ответ есть по поводу http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Naumov: Автор в предпоследнем предложении регулярку затребовал в явном виде, я даже как-то не подумал. Но вообще рекомендация хорошая конечно.

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев Я знаю просто считаю что стоит человеку, указывать на более простые и правильные пути решения. Так как он может не понимать что есть парсеры xml и html, и будет использовать везде регулярки, и получать страшно тормозящие и непростые в поддержки проэкты. Это довольно важный аспект, и мысль проста автор может и не знать о существование другого решения кроме как регулярки.

Comment: @Naumov: Я думаю для полноты картины вы можете упомянуть об этом в ответе рядом, или, если позволите, я добавлю ваше замечание в свой ответ.

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев конечно добавьте, именно это и добиваюсь ибо плодить ответы когда есть правильный уже не стоит.

Comment: @Naumov: Добавил вариант с расширением

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев Ok теперь заплюсовал

Comment: @Naumov: xD Спасибо.